# Why won't PhantomJSDriver use the capabilities I set?

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm setting some capabilities for `PhantomJsDriver`.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("cssSelectorsEnabled", false);
caps.setCapability("applicationCacheEnabled", true);
caps.setCapability("acceptSslCerts",true);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,phantomJsPath); 
this.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Then, I check what capabilities the driver is using:

```
System.out.println(driver.getCapabilities());
```

Output:

```
Capabilities [{
platform=XP, 
acceptSslCerts=false, 
javascriptEnabled=true, 
browserName=phantomjs,
rotatable=false,
driverVersion=1.1.0, 
locationContextEnabled=false, 
version=1.9.7, 
cssSelectorsEnabled=true, 
databaseEnabled=false, 
handlesAlerts=false, 
browserConnectionEnabled=false, 
proxy={proxyType=direct}, 
nativeEvents=true, 
webStorageEnabled=false, 
driverName=ghostdriver, 
applicationCacheEnabled=false, 
takesScreenshot=true}]
```

It shows:

```
cssSelectorsEnabled=true, 
applicationCacheEnabled=false,
acceptSslCerts=false
```

Why is the driver running without the capabilities I set?

Comment: I have the same issue. Setting acceptSslCerts=true does not work

Answer (score 19):

PhantomJS uses different mechanism in setting capabilities

```
static ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=false");
cliArgsCap.add("--ssl-protocol=any");
cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=true");
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_GHOSTDRIVER_CLI_ARGS,
        new String[] { "--logLevel=2" });
this.driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

For more information about its command line, you could reference http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html

Answer (score 1):

With **phantomjsdriver-1.1** I had to pass the follow arguments to get this to work.

```
cliArgsCap.add("--web-security=no");
cliArgsCap.add("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
```

Comment: How is this a better answer than the other one? What is `cliArgsCap`? The only thing that is different in your answer is `false` > `no` and `true` > `yes` which is interchangeable in PhantomJS. This does not warrant a new answer.

Comment: To get this to work I had to use phantomjsdriver-1.1 with "no" and "yes", with false and true it did not work.