# How to set proxy authentication in PhantomJS using selenium?

Tags: java, proxy, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, phantomjs

I'm running this simple selenium test in java:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfif"));
    element.sendKeys("cheese");
    element.submit();
    System.out.println("Titulo:"+driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
}
```

but here at my office it requires proxy authentication and I have no idea how to set it.

I have to put my user and password somewhere.

Can you help me out?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

PhantomJS uses the three proxy options that are set from the commandline ([docs](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html)).

> - `--proxy=address:port` specifies the proxy server to use (e.g. `--proxy=192.168.1.42:8080`).
> - `--proxy-type=[http|socks5|none]` specifies the type of the proxy server (default is `http`).
> - `--proxy-auth` specifies the authentication information for the proxy, e.g. `--proxy-auth=username:password)`.

To use these, you have to add them to the DesiredCapabilities map (as seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24626150) answer):

```
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=address:port");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-auth=username:password");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=http");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```