# Setup PhantomJS from JSON using WebDriver in Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

When running plain PhantomJS a config.json can be set which sets some options. How I can setup PhantomJS with JSON file when using the Selenium WebDriver?

I have this:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
caps.setCapability(
        PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
         "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Comment: i see here:http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html that i can configure phantomjs driver with json..but i not understand how i can this in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In plain PhantomJS a `--config=config.json` commandline option can be specified when running it as seen [here](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html). The same can be specified when invoking PhantomJS through the selenium webdriver by passing this commandline option through the capabilities:

```
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--config=config.json");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
capabilities.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
capabilities.setCapability(
    PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
     "/usr/local/bin/phantomjs");
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

This is adapted from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26931933/1816580).