# Setting proxy in RSelenium with PhantomJS

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver, proxy, phantomjs, rselenium

I'm using the `RSelenium` library with the argument `browserName = "phantomjs"` in the `remoteDriver` command, however I was looking to run a test where I specify the type of the proxy server. I've seen that proxy authentication is possible in, e.g. [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26931565/how-to-set-proxy-authentication-in-phantomjs-using-selenium), with the code used shown here:

```java
ArrayList<String> cliArgsCap = new ArrayList<String>();
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy=address:port");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-auth=username:password");
cliArgsCap.add("--proxy-type=http");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.setCapability(
PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, cliArgsCap);
WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Can the above be replicated in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
library(RSelenium)
pJS <- phantom(extras = c("--proxy=192.168.1.42:8080")
                           , "--proxy-auth=username:password"
                           , "--proxy-type=http")
)
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "phantomjs")
remDr$open()
```

Comment: By now phantom() is defunct. I think nowadays it is either RSelenium::rsDriver() or wdman::phantomjs(). Do you know how to set the proxy there? I couldnt find out...