# "undefined is not a function" on page login under Selenium (Java) using PhantomJS

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I'm trying to set up a crawler, using Selenium under Java.

When I use ChromeDriver it works fine. However, I get into a whole new bunch of problems if I try to use a headless browser like PhantomJS.

this is where problems happen:

```
     Capabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
     ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setJavascriptEnabled(true);
     ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
     ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("locationContextEnabled", true);
     ((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("acceptSslCerts", true);


    PhantomJSDriver jsDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    driver = jsDriver;
    System.out.println("driver is set...");
    driver.get("http://localhost/login");  //erorrs appears to be here
    System.out.println("gonna wait for page loading...");

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 40); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("emailAddr")));

    WebElement element_email = driver.findElement(By.id("emailAddr"));
    element_email.clear();
    element_email.sendKeys("example@example.com");

    WebElement element_password = driver.findElement(By.id("password"));
    element_password.clear();
    element_password.sendKeys("password");

    WebElement element_login = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type=\"submit\"]"));
    element_login.click();
```

the errors I get

```
driver is set...
[ERROR - 2015-08-27T11:45:32.378Z] Session [1c04b0e0-4cb1-11e5-aef3-a75ceb7c4223] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating '$("#location-search-box").geocomplete')

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-08-27T11:45:32.379Z] Session [1c04b0e0-4cb1-11e5-aef3-a75ceb7c4223] - page.onError - stack:
  init (http://localhost/static/js/auto/537c5ede-d569-491d-bd95-4916c763f9cf.js:9407)
  (anonymous function) (http://localhost/static/js/auto/537c5ede-d569-491d-bd95-4916c763f9cf.js:11336)
  l (http://localhost/static/js/jquery.min.js:2)
  fireWith (http://localhost/static/js/jquery.min.js:2)
  ready (http://localhost/static/js/jquery.min.js:2)
  A (http://localhost/static/js/jquery.min.js:2)

  :262 in error
gonna wait for page loading...
```

NOTE:

Program is still running but because of this error I was unable to login into the page.

How to solve this?

Is there any alternative?

EDIT one:

After following @Alfonso Presa I tried this:

```
String polyfill = "" +
        "       if (!Function.prototype.bind) {" +
        "                     Function.prototype.bind = function(oThis) {" +
        "                       if (typeof this !== 'function') {" +
        "                         // closest thing possible to the ECMAScript 5" +
        "                         // internal IsCallable function" +
        "                         throw new TypeError('Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable');" +
        "                       }" +
        "" +
        "                       var aArgs   = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)," +
        "                           fToBind = this," +
        "                           fNOP    = function() {}," +
        "                           fBound  = function() {" +
        "                             return fToBind.apply(this instanceof fNOP && oThis" +
        "                                    ? this" +
        "                                    : oThis," +
        "                                    aArgs.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));" +
        "                           };" +
        "" +
        "                       fNOP.prototype = this.prototype;" +
        "                       fBound.prototype = new fNOP();" +
        "" +
        "                       return fBound;" +
        "                     };" +
        "                   }" ;

PhantomJSDriver jsDriver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
jsDriver.executeAsyncScript(polyfill);
driver = jsDriver;
```

unfortunately it throws this error now :

```
[ERROR - 2015-08-27T13:05:25.354Z] Session [482dc570-4cbc-11e5-960c-81dcdf4848bd] - page.onError - msg: SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-08-27T13:05:25.354Z] Session [482dc570-4cbc-11e5-960c-81dcdf4848bd] - page.onError - stack:
  Function (undefined:2)
  Na (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():14)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():15)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():15)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():16)

  :262 in error
```

EDIT TWO:

after many trial, I install phantomJS version 1.9.8 and my original code just worked fine.

so overall:

1. phantomJS version 1.9.0 had many bugs (just take it as many bugs)
2. phantomJS version 2.0 had the above problem
3. phantomJS version 1.9.8 worked just fine. I will try to investigate what the problem might be.

Comment: Is this the only error that you see? It looks like the necessary JS file for "geocomplete" couldn't be loaded. Have you tried running it with `--web-security=false` if it's from another domain?

Comment: @ArtjomB. is this the line I need to add as part of my cababilities to try this out? `((DesiredCapabilities) caps).setCapability("web-security",false);`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24626150/1816580

Comment: @ArtjomB. thx mate, but unfortunately it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

PhantomJS is known to have some incompatibilities with web standards. Specially for your case this one: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522

The most probable cause for your problem is that the [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) method is being used in the web you're trying to crawl. That method is included in almost all browsers but PhantomJS.

To solve your issue, if you have the chance to change the web page you're crawling try to insert a polifyll like this one:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind#Polyfill

If that's not possible you can try to inject it using `executeScript` method.

Note that this seems to have been solved for Phantom 2.0.

Comment: PhantomJS 2.0.0 is out for a long time now. There just isn't a static build for linux.

Comment: that's great mate, I was using phantomJS 1.9 before and this wasn't an issue, however it was breaking at some other part. then decided to compile phantomJS 2.0. I'll try this and hopefully works :)

Comment: True... I was confused because of their github releases (seems like 2.0 is only tagged). Editing answer right now :-).

Comment: @AlfonsoPresa mate I've followed ur suggestion , I get some other error, I've edited question (under edit one) would you be able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the comments form the code you're injecting and use `executeScript` instead please

Comment: @AlfonsoPresa I tried that mate, it didn't work. however to my supprize I started playing with different version of phantomjs and version 1.9.8 worked...