# Unable to open pop up web form upon a button click in web application using PhantomJS in Selenium Java

Tags: java, angularjs, linux, selenium, phantomjs

I am currently working on a Selenium Java framework on an application built on  AngularJS. The problem that I am facing is, upon a button click, a pop up window (web form) should be launched (which works fine with IE/Chrome drivers), which is not being handled when running on a PhantomJS driver.

Error message displayed:

> Page.OnError: An Argument 'ObjectCreateController' is not a function and undefined

I am using Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: is javascript enabled on th e phantom js driver ?

Comment: @Sighil , we have enabled javascript in the driver

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247435/why-wont-phantomjsdriver-use-the-capabilities-i-set/24626150#24626150    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248774/undefined-is-not-a-function-on-page-login-under-selenium-java-using-phantomj